# Is there a GWT widget (or arrangment thereof) for 'open an editing context when the user selects an inline field''?

Tags: user-interface, gwt, naming

I'm not even sure what to call this UI technique, but consider the following example from IntelliJ IDEA.

### IntelliJ Example

Here, the 'field' is the return type of a method, and the 'editing context' is a drop-down of available types.  It's 'inline' because this is not a form with labelled fields, it's a 'narrative' (a statement in Java) instead.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA showing a drop-down to fulfill a field]

### My Application

I'm wanting to try the same kind of thing for a browser application I'm writing.  Here, the narrative would be something like:

> 'The appointment is sheduled for **1pm
>   today**.'

Here, the phrase '1pm today' is the 'phrase rendering' of a date-time field.  When the user selects it (via tabbing or clicking on it), a panel should 'pop up' beneath the phrase so that the field can be edited.  In this case, the editor might be a calendar widget and a time-spinner widget.

### Rough conceptualisation in GWT terms

It'd be nice to have a GWT widget which did something like:

- take a mix of widgets, where each widget has a 'text-phrase rendering' and (optionally) an 'editor panel'
- lay out all the rendered phrases in a text-friendly flow
- applied a consistent visual hint where a text-phrase had an editor, and
- displayed the editor underneath the rendering of the text-phrase in the flow, when the phrase was 'selected'

### The question

Does there exist something like this?  What is it called?  If I made one, what would I call it?

Comment: I think of this as "intellisense" - and I hope you make it!  I'd love to use something like this in a GWT app.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at GWT Showcase sample, Cell Sampler side menu. Click under DatePicker column.

http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

This is an open source sample

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fshowcase

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples%2Fshowcase%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fgwt%2Fsample%2Fshowcase%2Fclient%2Fcontent%2Fcell

Comment: partly.  The concepts present in the 'cell' - what with the 'editing' state and the 'renderer' and whatnot (I still haven't wrapped my head around them yet) seem to have parallels for what I'm after.  The main difference is that my 'phrase' equivalent wouldn't exist in a rigid tabular structure ... it would be laid out according to ordinary HTML flowed layout.